# Sub-Ethics: Subset or Strictly Inferior

Tags: metaethics

Do you know if philosophers have argued that certain ethical theories are contained in other ones? That is, that the set of imperatives in one for arbitrary agent is a subset of the imperatives on that agent? That is, that one expresses a strictly more minimal moralization than the other?

Also of interest is when adopting an ethical theory has a lesser effect in producing its aims than in adopting another ethical theory. For instance some people would argue that adopting utilitarianism as a person is destructive to the rights-based, often egoistic capitalist organization that "through invisible hand" maximizes total utility better than everyone trying to maximize total utility.